# TF Transformer model never overfits and just plateaus: Interpretation of this training curve and suggestions for improvement

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, transformer-model

This training curve is for a Transformer model that processes 2D (excluding batch) sequential signal and uses Adam optimizer, 32 batch size and for the learning rate: a custom LR Scheduler that replicates the warmup scheduler that is used at 'Attention is All You Need' paper. Training curve as below plateaus with eventual Training loss slightly lower than Validation loss, but training loss never starts back to climb, which I interpreted as the model never starts overfitting and just stops re-adjusting weights after around epoch 90.

Better interpretation and solutions to improve this model?

[image]

Below is my brief reproducible code:

```
x_train = np.random.normal(size=(32, 512, 512))
batch_size = 32
H, W = x_train.shape
rows, cols = np.indices((H, W), sparse=True)
padding_mask_init = np.zeros((H, W, W), dtype=np.bool_)
padding_mask_init[rows, 1:, cols] = 1
padding_mask = padding_mask_init[:batch_size]
embed_dim = 512
dense_dim = 2048
num_heads = 2
shape = (batch_size, embed_dim, 512) #(32, 512, 512)
decoder_inputs = layers.Input(batch_input_shape=shape, dtype=tensorflow.float16)
mha_1 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
mha_2 = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
layernorm_1 = layers.LayerNormalization()

Z = decoder_inputs
Z = mha_1(query=Z, value=Z, key=Z, use_causal_mask=True, attention_mask=padding_mask)
Z = layernorm_1(Z + decoder_inputs)
Z = mha_2(query=Z, value=decoder_inputs, key=decoder_inputs, attention_mask=padding_mask)
outputs = layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim, activation="softmax"))(Z)

model = keras.Model(decoder_inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule(embed_dim, 3000),beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.98,epsilon=1.0e-9), metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for more.

Comment: There is no point to put a bounty on a question that is off-topic, you are just wasting your time as this is not a programming problem, you could instead be asking in other sites like Data Science or AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** I will leave you with a blog post [source](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#baby) which explains nicely how to go about the training process of a deep neural network. I believe this will be helpful reading no matter what.

**Second,** a not climbing training loss can not be interpreted as non-overfitting. Rather, the missing validation loss climb could indicate that your model does not overfit.

In the end optimization is **all about capacity**. If you model is not able to overfit, you could try increasing the number of parameters of your model, or initially try to reduce the data to see whether you are able to overfit on a small subset of your overall dataset.

**Things to consider next:**

- Your learning rate might be too high (indicated by the steep drop and the "early" convergence)
- Your batch size is maybe a little too high (indicated by the small band width of your loss curves, but it is hard to say)
- Add layers and report back.

*Note:* Without knowing your data, this is really difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few things come to my attention:

1. You work with images (or 2D data)
2. CNN's are superb with image data... at least for local information extraction. Multiple kernels allow to extract many different aspects / features in one go, which is nice... but the receptive field is small. Very deep layers would solve this, but come with new problems.
3. You therefore use self attention (MHA with Q=K=V), which is a nice approach to allow the network gain a maximum receptive field. Information regardless of its spatial location is weighted according to the Q, K, V multiplication inside of MHA.
4. When reading CV papers, resolutions of 512 can be considered rather large and authors will always downsample the spatial dimensions before applying costly operations like self-attention.
5. Before a dog can be classified, a network will have to understand colors, lines, fur, eys, legs, and finally a dog. At the moment you waste the computation to perform something a CNN is very good at: understanding high frequency features (=local features). Since self-attention is expensive, one uses far less heads (you chose 2) than people would choose features in a CNN for doing the semantically the same: understand the "shallow" basics of the image.
6. I therefore highly recommend to down sample the data first with CNN layers, which are much more sparse in terms of parameters.
7. Only then, when the spatial dimension is reduced, use self-attention to find connections to distant locations that are important for your task.
8. The parameters saved by down sampling can be used to increase the number of heads. Each head can only understand a single concept. Similar to the number of channels in CNN's. Depending on the complexity of your task, you will certainly need more than 2. Numbers between 16-64 are better suited, if you can afford these numbers in terms of computation.

**Coming back to your learning curves**

From my point of view, your network might even have many parameters due to the MHA, but they are currently used in way the actual capacity is comparable low. This is the reason why your network shows no sign of over fitting, which is nicely explained in the answer by mrk. He also explained both approaches to "enforce" overfitting: (1) reduce data or (2) increase the capacity. Bot allows you to verify that your network "can" over fit. Currently that does not happen.

**My recommendations**

- Use a feature extractor (CNN) for down sampling and (local) feature extraction
- Later, apply self-attention to allow the network to understand how higher-level information is related across the spatial dimension
- Provide more information on the topic you're working on so we can give better feedback on loss, general approach etc.